# how can i add a report record in openerp odoo?

Tags: report, odoo, openerp-8

I'm using OpenERP 8 odoo 
and I'm following the report creation tutorial 
but I get stuck at where i can but the report record code 
for example:

```
      <report
      id="account_invoices"
      model="account.invoice"
      string="Invoices"
      report_type="qweb-pdf"
      name="account.report_invoice"
      file="account.report_invoice"
      attachment_use="True"
      attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and
      ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
      />
```

Thanks in advance 
Reference :
http://blog.emiprotechnologies.com/create-qweb-report-odoo/

Comment: What error you are facing? Can you post the error. Please tell us what is the exact problem.

Comment: my problem is where to add the report record code . in odoo 8 system

Comment: You have to write the code in a xml file, in a module. During updation of that module will read the data from that file and add that record into the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In General Directory file structure for creating the Qweb Report in ODOO**

**report** directory file contain

**__ init __.py file**

which is use as the manifest file for any python module its kind of entry point of the python module. (add the entry point of the your_report_parser_class_file.py file)

**your_report_parser_class_file.py file**

your report parser class file used to contain the report related function and variables which you want to call in future in your report (In Qweb View)

**view** directory file contain

**report_your_report_name.xml file**

Which is used to add the report view file it mean that the file will be displaying the for the Qweb View

(Generally its uses the bootstrap class andour custom css and Qweb template engine tags for designing the Qweb report and also this file has the added  in __ openerp__.py file )

**report_menu_file.xml file**

Add the menu xml file for add the menu to print the Qweb Report which is totally near and have the same folder as the __ openerp__.py file

(this file also has the add the entry in __ openerp__.py file )